# Comparar valor de input con elementos de un Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo esto de filter.

Primero mi html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Busqueda JavaScript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa algun nombre" id="nombre">  
        <button onclick="search()">Buscar Nombres</button>
        </div>

        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

El script

```js
const nombres = ['maria', 'Roberto', 'Jesus', 'Alejandro', 'Raul', 'Carla', 'Vanessa', 'Julia'];

const ask = document.getElementById('nombre').value;

const result = nombres.filter(nombres => nombres === ask);
```

Quiero saber por qué, a pesar de que el value del input se guarda en la variable, no puedo compararlo al usar filter dentro del array de 'nombres'.
Y sobre todo: ¿es la forma correcta o qué es lo usual para esto?

Comment: Probé tu código y funciona correctamente. No sé qué es exactamente lo que buscás.

Comment: Se supone que al ejecutar filter devuelve un nuevo array no?

Comment: Al ejecutar el boton de buscar nombre tendria que devolver el nombre introducido en el input

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) para encontrar elementos dentro del arreglo `nombres` que incluyan lo que esté escrito en `ask`.

**Nota:** si así está tu código entonces te hace falta crear la función `search()`

**Nota adicional:** Agregué el método [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) para que al buscar no se haga distinción de minúsculas y mayúsculas y pueda retornar todos los resultados, de otra forma la búsqueda `ro` solo devolvería `['Alejandro']`.

La razón por la que no te funciona es porque al utilizar `filter` estas utilizando `nombres` pero debes crear un "iterador" para recorrer el arreglo, por eso si se usa `nombre` funciona correctamente.

Ejemplo:

```js
function search(){
const nombres = ['Maria', 'Roberto', 'Jesus', 'Alejandro', 'Raul', 'Carla', 'Vanessa', 'Julia'];

const ask = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
console.log(ask);

const result = nombres.filter(nombre => nombre.toLowerCase().includes(ask));

console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Busqueda JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa algun nombre" id="nombre">  
    <button onclick="search()">Buscar Nombres</button>
    </div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo único que haría falta es que lo adaptes a tus necesidades, no sé si necesitas regresar el valor o imprimirlo en pantalla o algo, yo solo puse `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

El método [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada.

Como te comenté en tu pregunta, yo probé tu código y me funciona correctamente. Agregá esta línea para imprimir en la consola el resultado.

```
console.log(result);
```